# Creating a new file in the script folder using fopen

Tags: matlab, fopen

I'm using MATLAB R2017a and I would like to create a new binary file within the folder the script is running from.

I am running matlab as administrator since otherwise it has no permissions to create a file. The following returns a legal fileID:

```
fileID = fopen('mat.bin','w');
```

but the file is created in c:\windows\system32.

I then tried the following to create the file within the folder I have the script in:

```
filePath=fullfile(mfilename('fullpath'), 'mat.bin');
fileID = fopen(filePath,'w');
```

but I'm getting an invalid fileId (equals to -1).

the variable filePath is equal in runtime to

> 'D:\Dropbox\Studies\CurrentSemester\ImageProcessing\Matlab
>   Exercies\Chapter1\Ex4\mat.bin'

which seems valid to me.

I'd appreciate help figuring out what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`mfilename`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) returns the path *including the file name* (without the extension). From the documentation,

> `p = mfilename('fullpath')` returns the full path and name of the file in which the call occurs, not including the filename extension.

To keep the path to the folder only, use [`fileparts`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html), whose first output is precisely that. So, in your code, you should use

```
filePath = fullfile(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')), 'mat.bin');
```